# Android Studio cannot resolve resource variables

Tags: android, android-studio

Following a tutorial, I have a **styles.xml** file with the following code:

```
<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Sunshine" 
            parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
```

Android Studio gives me the error that **Widget.Appcompat.Light and Widget.Appcompat cannot be resolved**, although it still works at build time. I am a beginner and am quite at lost as to what caused this error. Any pointers?

On another related note, where do I find the list of default resources I can use, such as the Widget given to me above?

Thanks!

Comment: have added apcompact.v7.20+ library?

Comment: Yes, I have `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'` under dependencies